# Django: 'python manage.py runserver' gives "Segmentation fault" error

Tags: python, django

I just installed Python and Django for the first time while following [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) on the Django site, and everything up to this part worked just fine and produced no errors.

Now I'm at the "The development server" section, and ran the command `python manage.py runserver` while in my project directory where the `manage.py` is located and I get this error:

> Segmentation fault

Nothing else.

Anyone know what's going on here and how I can solve this?

If it matters, this is my manage.py file (the `django` in the `from django.core.management ...` line is marked as an error in my IDE (PyCharm) and the error says `Unresolved reference 'django'`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "davilex.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: if you think `Unresolved reference` is the issue .. you can find the relevant question in SO

Comment: A segmention fault usually related to a problem on a lower level than Python: C libraries, OS or even hardware. What system are you using?

Comment: Occurred for me when using Django with Postgres on python3.7.  Created a venv based on python3.6 and it worked fine

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me in a Django project where I had a lot of packages that had C-extensions. After I ran an Ubuntu system package update, I suddenly found that the `manage.py` command seg faulted. Turns out, some C-extensions link themselves to system libraries, and if a package update changes those libraries, it could cause the C-extensions to crash.

Since I had installed everything inside a Python virtualenv, I just deleted and regenerated it, and that fixed the error.

Comment: With pipenv, I needed to completely remove the directory of the virtualenv, just doing **pipenv uninstall --all** followed by **pipenv install** did not do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue following the tutorial pretty much verbatim (except that I am using git-bash in Windows, and used "virtualenv" in place of "mkvirtualenv" and "source projectdir/Scripts/activate" in place of "workon projectdir".

Running

```
python -vvvvv manage.py runserver
```

Gave me the warning that I had migrations that needed running (which the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) says to ignore) with

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Which is presumably not a step you can really skip in some cases, despite what the tutorial says. After this, runserver worked without error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while setting up a project on mac. In the end, turned out it because of value set in DATABASES.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'blue9',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'root',
    'PORT': '',
    'HOST': ''
}
```

Empty value of the 'PORT' and 'HOST' was causing the problem. These keys should not have an empty value. Either provide a finite value or don't specify them at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue related database config, first step check postgres library install config

```
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
```

second step
check database config in django project settings :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': '<database_name>',
    'USER': '<user_name>',
    'PASSWORD': '<password>',
    'HOST': '<host-name>',
    'PORT': '<port number : default : 5432>',
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. install PyMysql:

   `python3 -m pip install PyMysql`
2. Setting add mysql conf:

   ```
   DATABASES = {  
       'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'your database name',
       'USER': 'your user',
       'PASSWORD': 'your pwd',
       'HOST': 'ip',
       'PORT': 'port',
       }
   }
   ```
3. __init__.py add
   `import pymysql`
   `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()`

enjoy~