# python manage.py runserver Segmentation fault

Tags: python, django, segmentation-fault, manage.py

I just installed python and Django.
and now when i running

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

it is showing me this error

```
Segmentation fault
```

Please help me get out of this. i appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: does it help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735659/django-python-manage-py-runserver-gives-segmentation-fault-error ?

Comment: i have alreaddy saw that. but it didn't worked

Comment: i just start a new command Prompt window (run as administrator)

and run the same command again

an it worked!

Comment: hi @m-suleman-khan, would you mind putting your comment as an answer, please? It will definitely help other people. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Well i have solved it my self.

i just start a new command Prompt window (run as administrator)

and run the same command again

an it worked!

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you have installed the packages in the virtual environment correctly. In my case, I was having trouble with torch library installation
- Ensure that you choose an server/instance with enough memory.

This worked out well for me.

Comment: what does the torch library have to do with OP's Django server?