# python manage.py migrate Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal

Specs:

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Interpeter: Python 3.6.5

When i run the command `sudo python manage.py migrate` or `sudo python manage.py runserver` this is the output i get:

> Segmentation fault: 11

[Django: 'python manage.py runserver' gives "Segmentation fault" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735659/django-python-manage-py-runserver-gives-segmentation-fault-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

There is another post out there with similar questions and suggestions but its never resolved. And i tried suggestions from there but none of it worked out for me.

This is part of my `settings.py` file regarding migration

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangoproject',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'test123',
        'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'PORT': '3306'
    } }
```

Any new suggestions? I am stuck.

EDIT:

- error also occurs with pip3 or python3
- When i run sudo python3 manage.py runserver

Comment: Hmm, did you try setting HOST to localhost or 127.0.0.1 for local testing?

Comment: did you try `python3 manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735659/django-python-manage-py-runserver-gives-segmentation-fault-error?noredirect=1&lq=1 this might help

Comment: @sgauri Yes i have run python3 unfortunately the same problem. I already mentioned in my description that the post did not work out for me.

Comment: @AriK yes i have same problem occurs.